# VBA- how to reset defined variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code as below and i want to reset "add" as 1 when a new loop starts for the next row.

```
Sub Group()
    DataBook = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Dim i As Long
    RowCount = 1
    RowCount2 = 1
    Add = 1
    For i = 19 To 1819
        If Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets("Template").Range("G" & i).IndentLevel = 8 Then
            Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, 2) = Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets("Template").Range("G" & i).Value
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
            If Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets("Template").Range("G" & i - Add).IndentLevel = 7 Then
                Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount2, 1) = Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets("Template").Range("G" & i - Add)
                RowCount2 = RowCount2 + 1
                Add = Add + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: [I indented your code](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation)... doesn't that read well now?

Answer (score 2):

Switch these two lines:

```
Add = 1
For i = 19 To 1819
```

I.e:

```
For i = 19 To 1819
    Add = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) this did work and set "add" as 1. However, the add=add+1 loop not functions after this change.

Comment: @LiangWu Are you sure of the position of the add = add + 1? Did you try moving it further down to see if you got the desired result?